# Is there any notion of device independent test for correlation like quantum discord?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, bells-inequality

A Device independent test is a procedure used to characterise quantum resources with the minimal level of trust. If one wants to test correlations like entanglement in a device-independent way, we get non-local correlations.

Then my question is: given that Quantum Discord is considered as a form of quantum correlation that has no classical analogous, is it possible to test in a device-independent way? Has anybody addressed this question in the past years?

If the answer is no, then a second question comes: is quantum discord really a notion about "correlations", if it can not be tested in a device-independent experiment?

Comment: I do not know about quantum discord, but what is the idea here? To prove that each device is independent by testing a single device?

Comment: @Mauricio No, Device Independent tests are tests that do not trust any particular theory to asserts specific conclusions, i.e. they are sort of theory-independent and relies only on experimental data (frequencies of observed outcomes). For instance, not all entangled states are non-local, i.e. some entangled states can not pass a Bell test, i.e. they do not possess non-local feature. For a bit of background of Device Independence tests, see the editorial https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/18/10/100202/pdf